Why does differentiation with respect to time commute with the Fourier Transform?
In Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis, they often invoke the fact that differentiation with respect to time commutes with the Fourier transform  with respect to space variables.
For example, on page 147 (Chapter 5, Proof of Theorem 2.1(i)), they show that $u(x, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 t\xi^2} e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi$ is infinitely differentiable by commuting the derivative with the integral, i.e. $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 t\xi^2} e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 t\xi^2} e^{2\pi i\xi x}d\xi$.
Another example is on page 185, motivating the solution to the Wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^d$, they say that "differentiation with respect to $t$ commutes with the Fourier transform in the space variables".
My question is, what is the justification for this? I can't seem to find in the book where they prove this claim.
In short, why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}FT(f(x, y)) = FT(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x, y))$ where the Fourier transform, $FT$, is taken w.r.t. $x$?
EDIT
Many answers below point to the Liebniz rule, which I am familiar with. However, I think we cannot directly use the Liebniz rule to solve this problem since we are dealing with integration over an unbounded set while the Liebniz rule only applies to integration over a bounded set.
In particular, by the Liebniz rule, for any function $f$ that is continuously differentiable,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx &= \int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x, t)dx \\
\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx &= \lim_{L\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x, t)dx \\
\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x, t)dx
\end{align*}
$$
In particular, to show commutativity between integration and derivation, we want $\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx =\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, t)dx$, how do we do this?

Read about differentiation under the integral sign.

Or this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

I’m aware of Liebniz’s rule but that only applies to proper integrals, whereas here we are commuting the derivative with an improper integral. How do you deal with that?

What you call Leibniz' rule (exchange of integral and derivative) holds without problems on unbounded intervals, if you are in a setting where you can use the dominated convergence theorem on the derivative of the integrand. The answer of Steven shows that. And you can prove this general fact by hand: take the incremental ratio, pull the integral outside the fraction, use dominated convergence. Not difficult. It's harder to remember the assumptions of the theorem rather than knowing how to replicate the proof.

@LorenzoPompili While the DCT is more powerful, one can also appeal to the uniform convergence of the "differentiated integrand," which justifies the interchange of operators.

@MarkViola sure, but that needs a bounded interval, right? I was talking about the case of unbounded intervals

@LorenzoPompili No, the integration limits need not be bounded.  Suppose that $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ exist and are continuous.  If $\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},dy$ converges uniformly for $x\in [c,d]$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x,y),dy$ converges $\forall x$. Then $\int_0^\infty f(x,y),dy$ is differentiable and $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty f(x,y),dy=\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x},dy$$

@MarkViola I thought you were assuming that $\partial_xf(x,y)$ converges uniformly as $x\to x_0$, that's why I said the above. What do you mean by $\int_0^\infty \partial_x f(x,y),dy$ converges uniformly? That $\lim_{M\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[c,d]}\int_M^\infty |\partial_x f(x,y)|,dy=0$? If so I agree, since the continuity of the integrand implies uniform integrability, and we fall in the hypotheses of Vitali's convergence theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

@LorenzoPompili Here is the definition:  For an improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x,y),dy$, where $y\in S$, uniform convergence means that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a number $M$ such that for all $y\in S$ and all $x' >M$, we have $$\left|\int_{x'}^\infty f(x,y),dx\right| <\varepsilon$$.

There is nothing that special about the Fourier transform, if you derive in the variable that you are not transforming. Differentiation commutes with bounded linear operators in general. Say, if you have a $C^1$ function $\gamma$ from $\mathbb R$ to a Banach space $X$, and a linear, bounded operator $L$ from $X$ to another B.sp. $Y$, then the composition $L\circ\gamma=:\eta$ is a $C^1$ function from $\mathbb R$ to $Y$ and it satisfies
$$ d/dt \,\eta(t)= L(d/dt\, \gamma(t)). $$
This is because when you look at the definition of derivative, the linear operator applied to the incremental ratio $(\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t))/h$ yields $L((\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t))/h)=(\eta(t+h)-\eta(t))/h$ by linearity, and then the limit as $h\to 0$ commutes with $L$ since $L$ is continuous.
The above is a nice case, where the curve is $C^1$ on a given space where the operator $L$ acts. In your case, the operator $L$ is the Fourier transform, which is continuous from some spaces to some different spaces, and the curve $y\mapsto f(\cdot,y)$ could be a continuous curve with values in some vector space $X$, but the $y$ derivative could belong to a different space $Z$. The above argument has to be modified accordingly, but the principle is always the same: write the incremental ratio, use the linearity of the Fourier transform to let it slide inside the numerator of the fraction, and then try to show that the limit coincides with the ansatz. You will have to use some continuity property of the Fourier Transform at some point. That is to say that in principle, the linearity of the Fourier transform and its continuity in suitable norms are all you need if you differentiate in the variable that you are not transforming.
Edit. This answer is complementary to those that commute integration and derivative. You have to be careful with that, because often the integral defining the Fourier transform is not defined in the usual sense for every $\xi$, for instance when you define the Fourier transform on $L^2$. In that case you have to use some density arguments to make the argument rigorous.

This comes from a general property about integrals, namely that for a "nice/smooth" function $g(x,t)$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_Sg(x,t)\mathrm dx=
\int_S\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}g(x,t)\mathrm dx
$$
This follows from the properties of sums of derivatives. Consider a simple Riemann sum.
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\sum_{i=-n^2}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n}\cdot g\left(\frac{i}{n},t\right)=\sum_{i=-n^2}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}g\left(\frac{i}{n},t\right)
$$
Taking the limit $n\to\infty$, we (usually) get the integral above, and and this equality still holds. In the context of the Fourier Transform, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}FT(f)(\zeta,t)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,t)e^{2\pi i\zeta x}\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(x,t)e^{2\pi i\zeta x}\mathrm dx =FT(\tfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f)(\zeta,t),
$$
using that $e^{2\pi \zeta x}$ is a constant with respect to $t$.

So I understand the conclusion of this argument is essentially Liebniz’s rule when $S$ is a bounded set, but here we are dealing with integration over the entire real line. How do we go from Liebniz’s rule which applies to integration on a bounded set to all of $\mathbb{R}$?

@MasheBurnedead the leibniz rule applies to any bounded set, and the improper integral is a limit of integrals over bounded sets. So apply the leibniz rule to each bounded set and take limits. (For a more rigorous version of this, you should learn about Lebesgue integration).

I am familiar with Lebesgue integration, could you explain how to apply convergence theorems from Lebesgue integration to this context?
This is what I have so far - I agree that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx = \int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x, t)dx$. Taking the limit of both sides as $L\rightarrow \infty$, we get $\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x, t)dx$.

In particular, we want $\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx =\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \lim_{L\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x, t)dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, t)dx$ but showing that involves swapping the derivative with a limit, and I don't see how results from Lesbesgue's theory of integration can help with this.

Use dominated convergence to argue from the outset, not limits of integrals over finite intervvals.

As commented by Ted Shifrin, dominated convergence implies differentiation under the integral, see this question for example. The integrals there are over all of $\mathbb{R}$.
For example, for your $t$ derivative you can apply this once you show that the absolute value of the function
$$
(\xi,t) \mapsto -4 \pi^2 \xi^2 \cdot \hat{f}(\xi)e^{-4\pi^2 t\xi^2} e^{2\pi i\xi x}
$$
is dominated by some integrable function $g(\xi)$ of $\xi$. Now I had to look up in your book that $t>0$ (you should've probably included this in the question), so we have $t>t_0>0$ for some $t_0$. So we can pick
$$
g(\xi)= 4 \pi^2 \xi^2 \cdot |\hat{f}(\xi)|e^{-4\pi^2 t_0\xi^2}, 
$$
which is integrable as I'll leave to you (use theorem 1.12 on page 143 of your book to see that $\hat{f}$ is integrable).
